# How many different arrangements of the letters in "HYPERGEOMETRIC" begin and end with "E"?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many different arrangements of the letters in "HYPERGEOMETRIC" begin and end with "E"?

is it just this?: 13!/2! = 3113510400 arrangements that begin and end with e

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's fix two $ E'$s as the first and the last letter of the word that will be created:

$E\underbrace{-----\cdots ----}_{12 \text {letter}}E$

Thus the result :  $\dfrac {12!}{2!}$ , since there are two $R$'s among the remaining letters(HYPRGOMETRIC) we divide by $2!$ to eliminate overcounting

Comment: Aha, thank you. When correcting the previous answer provided, I realized that it is in fact 12! because 2 e's are omitted from the possible letters, as they are designated to the first and last position.